# Closing Elementor Tabs on Click

Tags: jquery, tabs, elementor

I am trying to create tabs that collapse when clicking the selected/highlighted tab again (Google Image results is a good example of this). I found a few scripts on here but don't know how to tailor them for elementor or if it's even applicable using a script. Here's a JSFiddle of what I'm going for:
http://jsfiddle.net/x8rfge06/

I found this script to close tabs/accordions on load:

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
var delay = 10; setTimeout(function() { 
$('.elementor-tab-title').removeClass('elementor-active');
$('.elementor-tab-content').css('display', 'none'); }, delay); 
}); 
</script>
```

And this general tab-closing on click, not tailored to elementor:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var el = "";
jQuery('ul.tabs li').click(function () {
    var tab_id = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab');
    jQuery('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    jQuery('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    if(tab_id != el){
      jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    jQuery("#" + tab_id).addClass('current'); 
    }

   el = tab_id;       
})
})
```

Is this doable or something out of elementor's capabilities! thank you

Comment: any luck with this? I'm running into the same exact issue.

Comment: @Mixmastermiike I scavenged the internet and couldn't find an answer. If you have an in-house engineer, they might be able to help.

Comment: I'm getting super close with this custom jquery I made...  the only problem is though, that after the heading is closed, and when you re-open it... the elementor-active class is missing each time. 

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $(".elementor-tab-title").click(function(){
    $(".elementor-tab-content.elementor-active").toggle();
  $(this).removeClass("elementor-active");
  });
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working jQuery code to implement that :

```
jQuery('.elementor-tab-mobile-title').click(function () {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('elementor-active');     
  jQuery(this).next().toggleClass('elementor-active');      
  jQuery(this).next().toggle();     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_jquery() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery' );
}    
add_action('init', 'add_jquery');
//-------------------- 
echo '<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
//---------------------
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".elementor-tab-mobile-title").click(function(){
jQuery(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
  
});
});
</script>';
```

I added this at the end of the child themes function.php
its 100% working in my webpage

you can toggle elementor tabs from mobile using this code